# How can i read a number in c with a function and use it in main?

Tags: c

i try to read a number from keyboard with a function, but it doesn't work. This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void write(int *n);

int main()
{
    int *n,*m,p;
    write(&n);
    write(&m);
    p = *n + *m;

    printf("p = %d",p);
}

void write(int *n)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` ==> `scanf("%d",n);` because `n` is already a pointer.

Comment: ... and remove every `*` in `main`.

Comment: ... and enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: On POSIX and many other systems `write` is a function of the standard library. You should use a different name.

Comment: I replace write with other word and i add scanf("%d",&n); ==> scanf("%d",n); but it doesn't work

EDIT: solved :D

Comment: we could start with the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Then your function names should not be the same as well known system function names I.E. ` write()` is a very poor name to use, especially as the function is not writing.

Comment: the code is defining all the local variables `m` and `n` as being pointers, but the code does not ever have them point to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applying all the comments to the posted code and following the axiom:

*only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

and checking the returned value from `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful

results in:

```
#include <stdio.h> // scanf(), printf(), fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

void getInteger(int *n);

int main( void )
{
    int n;
    int m;
    int p;
    getInteger(&n);
    getInteger(&m);
    p = n + m;

    printf("p = %d",p);
}

void getInteger(int *n)
{
    if( 1 != scanf("%d",n) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

and when run with an input of: '1 3' the output is

```
p = 4
```